# Tutorials on convolution networks and autoencoders

Tags: references, neural-networks

As said in a respected blog, "Maybe it’s too early to call, but [...] it looks like Neural Networks are making a comeback." Some of the networks that are currently developed are Autoencoders and Convolution Networks. Where could one find some tutorials/articles on these topics?

Comment: Richard Socher wrote the [blog post in question](http://hunch.net/?p=1852).

Answer (score 6):

Andrew Ng's cs294a course at Stanford *Deep Learning and Unsupervised Feature Learning* has some nice freebies on sparse autoencoders:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/video1.html
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/video2.html
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder_2011new.pdf

See at the bottom of: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/handouts.htm